# DefaultValue Attribute in C#

Tags: c#, attributes

I want to use on DefaultValue Attribute to define default value for custom class that I write in my App. the class gives in his constractor a string.
I write the follow:

```
[DefaultValue(Type.GetType("MyClass"),"hello world")]
```

but when I try to run this App. I give error:

> "An attribute argument must be a
>   constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an
>   attribute parameter type".

can anyone explain me what the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `Type.GetType("MyClass")` where you should have `typeof(MyClass)`.

Comment: it works, but now I can't success to give the value of this attribute. what sould I write to give it?

Comment: I think you need to explain in detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: I try to build an enum that the his values are not int or char. so I write before each value - [DefaultValue(Type.GetType("MyClass"),"11:00:00")] and in the ctor of the MyClass I parss the string. but now how can I recive for each value the value that I write in the  DefaultValue Attribute?

Comment: In C# the enum values must be an integer type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469287/c-vs-java-enum-for-those-new-to-c might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect its the Type.GetType("MyClass");

can you try typeof(MyClass) instead, passing the type and not a string?

Comment: it works, but now I can't success to give the value of this attribute. what sould I write to give it?

Comment: Are you getting an error? i just read this: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32319410/defaultvalue-attribute-on-properties-of-user-controls.aspx it explains a little on when the value would be visible. I must admit I have not used DefaultValueAttributes before put I might be able to help if you can give a little more detail. The other guys on this thread may be able to help also if they see this comment

Answer (score 1):

`Type.GetType()` is a method (i.e. not a constant expression), as the others said, use `typeof`.

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(MyClass),"Convertible String")]
```

**Edit:** To enable the conversion of the string to your custom class you need to associate a TypeConverter with it, see the examples-section of [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1z9x06x.aspx) to get an idea of how to do so.

Comment: it works, but now I can't success to give the value of this attribute. what sould I write to give it?

Comment: I haven't used the DefaultValue attribute much, but when i did, i never needed to give it a type, i just entered some value like this for a bool: [DefaultValue(false)], since you want to use a more complex type you should look into how it tries to convert the value, maybe your class needs to implement an interface for it to work.