# Private value in C# flags enumeration

Tags: c#, design-patterns, enums, flags

I'm creating a flags enumeration in C#, similar to the following:

```
    [Flags]
    public enum DriversLicenseFlags
    {
        None = 0,

        Suspended = 1 << 1,
        Revoked   = 1 << 2,

        Restored  = 1 << 3,
        SuspendedAndRestored = Suspended | Restored,
        RevokedAndRestored   = Revoked   | Restored,
    }
```

A couple notes about my intentions here:

- `Suspended` and `Revoked` are unique states that can, but don't necessarily lead to a restore.
- `Restored` should only be possible if the user has also been `Suspended` or `Revoked` (or both).  It's important to track specifically which event was the precursor to the restore.
- A license can be both `Suspended` and `Revoked` (and `Restored`)

Also, I'm trying to stick to suggestions made in MSDN's [Designing Flags Enumerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062(v=VS.100).aspx).  In particular:

- **Consider providing special enumeration values for commonly used combinations of flags.**

  - `SuspendedAndRestored` and `RevokedAndRestored` will both be common.
- **Avoid creating flags enumerations when certain combinations of values are invalid.**

  - This is my problem, because `Restored` is not valid unless at least one of `Suspended` and `Revoked` is set.

Ideally, I'd like a value for `Restored` to be present in the enum for internal usage, but only available to set publicly via some valid combination.  Unfortunately, `internal` isn't a valid modifier for enum values.

I've thought of a few alternatives, but each seems to have drawbacks:

1. Keep `Restored` as a public value, note the limitations in comments and do a precondition check for invalid combinations on public APIs.

   This would work, and is likely the solution I will go with.  However, it seems like their should be a cleaner solution.
2. Use an enhanced, java-like enum as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469287/c-vs-java-enum-for-those-new-to-c) and define `Restored` as `internal static`.

   This would also work, but feels like overkill because I don't need any of the other functionality at this point.
3. Don't define `Restored` as a value, but reserve the value for OR'ing, and for checking the value in consuming methods.  i.e.:

   ```
   internal const int RestoredFlag = 1 << 3;
   [Flags]
   public enum DriversLicenseFlags
   {
       None = 0,

       Suspended = 1 << 1,
       Revoked   = 1 << 2,

       SuspendedAndRestored = Suspended | RestoredFlag,
       RevokedAndRestored   = Revoked   | RestoredFlag,
   }
   ```

This feels hacky me, both in how it's defined and how it will be used internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to use `Flags` specifically? Is this not exactly what you are after?

```
public enum DriversLicenseStatus
{
    None = 0,
    Suspended,
    Revoked,
    SuspendedAndRestored,
    RevokedAndRestored,
}
```

It will certainly be easy to make sure that only "valid" transitions are made from within the property setters of the `DriversLicenseStatus` properties.

If for some reason you definitely want to use `Flags` internally, then you can define a separate `private enum DriversLicenseStatusFlags` and convert from that to only expose `DriversLicenseStatus` values in your public interface.

Another option which could be worth considering is splitting the enum into two values:

```
bool IsActive;

enum InactiveReason {
    None = 0,
    Suspended,
    Revoked,
}
```

The "AndRestored" cases would be those with `IsActive == true` and `InactiveReason != InactiveReason.None`.

I get the distinct impression that you are over-engineering here. :)

Comment: You forgot `SuspendedAndRevoked` an `SuspendedAndRevokedAndRestored`.

Comment: @Jan: I don't think `SuspendedAndRevoked` makes sense. If it has been revoked, that's that.

Comment: It's what he asks for: `Restored` should only be possible if the user has also been `Suspended` or `Revoked` **(or both)**

Comment: @Jan: I think you are misreading the OP's intent. Notice that he has not defined those values either.

Comment: Good point.  In my situation, it's also valid to be both Suspended and Revoked (and Restored).  In that situation it would likely be more confusing if Restored isn't exposed.

Comment: @ScottWegner, @Jan: My bad then :)

Comment: @Jon, I like the idea of splitting it up into two separate variables for some "active" status and inactive reason.  re: over-engineering, yes absolutely :)

Answer (score 2):

Option 3 seems as good an idea as anything to me. Bear in mind that .NET enums will not throw exceptions when they are set to undefined values, so there is nothing preventing your users from saying:

```
PrintDriversLicenseStatus(42);
```

... where `PrintDriversLicenseStatus` takes a `DriversLicenseFlags` as its argument.

So you'll need to have each method check its inputs anyway to make sure they're a defined value.

#### Edit

One other option for your consideration: Create a special internal enum class, and cast arguments to it for internal use:

```
[Flags]
public enum DriversLicenseFlagsInternal
{
    None = 0,

    Suspended = 1 << 1,
    Revoked   = 1 << 2,

    Restored  = 1 << 3,
    SuspendedAndRestored = Suspended | Restored,
    RevokedAndRestored   = Revoked   | Restored,
}

[Flags]
internal enum DriversLicenseFlags
{
    None = DriversLicenseFlagsInternal.None,

    Suspended = DriversLicenseFlagsInternal.Suspended,
    Revoked   = DriversLicenseFlagsInternal.Revoked,

    SuspendedAndRestored = DriversLicenseFlagsInternal.SuspendedAndRestored,
    RevokedAndRestored   = DriversLicenseFlagsInternal.RevokedAndRestored,

}


public void DoSomething(DriversLicenseFlags arg)
{
    var argAsInternal = (DriversLicenseFlagsInternal) arg;
// or var argAsInternal = Util.CheckDefinedDriversLicense(arg);
}
```

Not sure if this is any better, but it may feel less hacky.

Comment: Sure, I can't guarantee that my users won't explicitly do strange/malicious things.  However, I hope my design will discourage it. :)

Comment: @Scott Wegner: ... which is why I think option 3 is the best. It effectively presents users with only the logical options, without going to extremes. Create some internal utility methods to help check whether the drivers license is restored, etc., so the hackiness will all reside in a single class.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for flags and create a validate method

```
[Flags]
public enum DriversLicenseFlags {
    None,
    Suspended,
    Revoked,
    Restored
}

public bool Validate(DriversLicenseFlags flags) {
    if(flags.HasFlag(DriversLicenseFlags.Restored)) {
        return 
            flags.HasFlag(DriversLicenseFlags.Revoked) || 
            flags.HasFlag(DriversLicenseFlags.Suspended);

        // Or throw an exception
     }
     return true;
}
```

If you can live with it being against the Microsoft recommendation. I see it as an edge case.