# Java - Issue with functions/varibles inside an enum and a constructor

Tags: java, enums

I have been trying to understand what is going on in this piece of **Java** code, but so far I didn't manage. This is part of this [library](https://github.com/egueli/TraCI4J) .

My wonders are on

```
CURRENT_SIM_TIME(Constants.VAR_TIME_STEP), NET_BOUNDARIES(Constants.VAR_NET_BOUNDING_BOX)
```

They do not appear previously in the code and later on, there is one constructor which uses `CURRENT_SIM_TIME` without any brackets `()`.

```
enum Variable {
        CURRENT_SIM_TIME(Constants.VAR_TIME_STEP), NET_BOUNDARIES(
                Constants.VAR_NET_BOUNDING_BOX), ;
        public final int id;
        private Variable(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
}
```

This the constructor I was talking about:

```
SimulationData(DataInputStream dis, DataOutputStream dos) {
        super("", Variable.class);
        addReadQuery(Variable.CURRENT_SIM_TIME,
                new ReadObjectVarQuery.IntegerQ(dis, dos,
                        Constants.CMD_GET_SIM_VARIABLE, "",
                        Variable.CURRENT_SIM_TIME.id) {

                });

        addReadQuery(Variable.NET_BOUNDARIES,
                new ReadObjectVarQuery.BoundingBoxQ(dis, dos,
                        Constants.CMD_GET_SIM_VARIABLE, "",
                        Variable.NET_BOUNDARIES.id));

        this.dis = dis;
        this.dos = dos;

    }
```

So, how is this possible?

Inside the enum Variable we have `CURRENT_SIM_TIME` and `NET_BOUNDARIES` with an argument inside the brackets and then in the constructor  we create an `addReadQuery` with `Variable.CURRENT_SIM_TIME` as well as `Variable.NET_BOUNDARIES`, without brackets as an argument.

Are these functions? Static variables? Are they be defined in some other part of the code and I am not able to find them?

I am really lost right now...

Comment: Java enums allow such constructs; they are basically classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 2):

**Declaring Enum :**

```
enum Variable {
        CURRENT_SIM_TIME(Constants.VAR_TIME_STEP), NET_BOUNDARIES(
                Constants.VAR_NET_BOUNDING_BOX), ;
        public final int id;
        private Variable(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
}
```

So when you say `CURRENT_SIM_TIME(Constants.VAR_TIME_STEP)` inside your enum declaration, you are calling the constructor `Variable(int id)` such that for enum `CURRENT_SIM_TIME` the value of the `id` variable will be set to `Constants.VAR_TIME_STEP` for that enum itself.

Similar is the case for `NET_BOUNDARIES`

So if you want to get the value of `id` for `CURRENT_SIM_TIME`, you would do it like :

`Variable.NET_BOUNDARIES.id`

**Using Enum**

And when you use enum, you don't have to call it with constructor, because that's already done when you declare your enum. So you just use the enum.

Comment: Ok! Now I undestand it! Just one comment. I am trying to create a C# equivalent for this, so would you recommend me doing the conversion as shown in this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469287/c-sharp-vs-java-enum-for-those-new-to-c

Comment: You could do it depending on your requirement, but that will be only a method for enum like what you have for classes, which you could call like `Variable.NET_BOUNDARIES.someMethodDefinedInVariableEnum()`