# Convert from Java to C#

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I need to write this code in C#. Any help would be appreciated. 
The interface and the first class is where the issues are. How can I convert that into C#? EnumByteConverter & EnumByteConverter>? 
Is this even possible? What would my options be?

```
public interface EnumByteConverter<E extends Enum<E> & EnumByteConverter<E>>
{
  byte convert();
  E convert(byte val);
}




public class ReverseByteEnumMap<V extends Enum<V> & EnumByteConverter>
{
  private Map<Byte, V> map = new HashMap<>();

  public ReverseByteEnumMap(Class<V> valueType)
  {
    for (V v : valueType.getEnumConstants())
    {
      map.put(v.convert(), v);
    }
  }

  public V get(byte num)
  {
    return map.get(num);
  }
}




public enum Transport implements EnumByteConverter<Transport>
{
  FrameFormatB(0), 
  FrameFormatA(1), 
  FrameDraft(254),
  FrameUnknown(255);

  private static ReverseByteEnumMap<Transport> map = new ReverseByteEnumMap<>(Transport.class);
  private final byte value;

  Transport(int value)
  {
    this.value = (byte) value;
  }

  public byte convert()
  {
    return value;
  }

  public Transport convert(byte val)
  {
    return map.get(val);
  }

  public static Transport get(byte val)
  {
    return map.get(val);
  }
}
```

This is what I have tried. I managed to implement the interface using struct, and the reverse class with similar thing.

```
  public interface IEnumByteConverter<E> where E : struct
  {
    byte Convert();
    E Convert(byte val);
  }
}



  public class ReverseByteEnumMap<T> where T : struct, IEnumByteConverter<T>
  {
    private Dictionary<Byte, T> map = new Dictionary<Byte, T>();
    private IEnumByteConverter<T> converter;

    public ReverseByteEnumMap(T valueType)
    {
      foreach (T t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
        map.Add(t.Convert() , t);
    }

    public T Get(byte num)
    {
      return map[num];
    }
  }


  public class Transport : IEnumByteConverter<TransportEnums>
  {

    public enum TransportEnums
    {
      FrameFormatB = 0,
      FrameFormatA = 1,
      FrameDraft = 254,
      FrameUnknown = 255
    }

    private static ReverseByteEnumMap<Transport> map = new ReverseByteEnumMap<Transport> ();
    private byte value;

    Transport(int value)
    {
      this.value = (byte)value;
    }

    public byte Convert()
    {
      return value;
    }

    public TransportEnums Convert(byte val)
    {
      return map.Get(val);
    }

    public static TransportEnums Get(byte val)
    {
      return map.Get(val);
    }

  }
```

But I got stuck in the last class. I cannot use the Transport.class nor enums. I cannot tell if this a right path I am heading on

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It's perfectly possible but unfortunately SO isn't a code writing service. Feel free to come back with a specific on-topic question!

Comment: @Lucas In his defense, the code seems to be a little complex. I wouldn't know how to translate it (but I don't do java). It would be more easy for me to rework it based on the specifications than by translating it line-by-line.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I'll say that translating 1:1 is absolutely impossible. In C# you can't subclass an `enum`. You can try to build something similar, but it won't be very much similar.

Comment: @calliste As is the code can't be translated. What is possible is, given enough use cases to build something similar.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a service, but I trust stackoverflow community to help each other, and that is what I was looking for: a little guidance.

Comment: It would be better if you showed us what you tried to do and ask for help

Comment: I have updated the question and how I tried to implement all this

Comment: @xanatos obviously 1:1 translation is impossible unless you're working with a superset/subset, no one asked for that. point is that you _can_ translate from Java to C# the same way you translate from German to French.

Answer (score 1):

In C# it is (quite) easy to change the base type of an `enum`:

```
public enum Transport : byte
{
    FrameFormatB = 0,
    FrameFormatA = 1,
    FrameDraft = 254,
    FrameUnknown = 255
}
```

and it is quite easy to convert from the `enum` to the base type and back:

```
Transport t1 = (Transport)255; // Equivalent to = Transport.FrameUnknown

int i1 = (int)t1; // 255
byte b1 = (byte)t1; // 255
```

So you don't need all the support code that you wrote.

In Java `enum` are classes that don't normally have a "value", and if you want to give them a numerical value you have to do like what is written in your code: define a `value` field. Then you have to add methods to go from the `enum` "name" to its "value" and back.

The main problem here is that the C# (.NET) `enum` can in truth have any value, not only the defined ones:

```
Transport t2 = (Transport)100;
```

while in Java only the defined values of `enum` are legal (because they are the only instances of the `enum` class that are defined. Other instances can't be created). See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/469315/613130 .

The code you wrote is quite similar to this one: http://dan.clarke.name/2011/07/enum-in-java-with-int-conversion/

Comment: Thank you for the answer @xanatos I will check the links. It is only how the interface was written. And when it is not your code, it is harder to work your way around it