# Enum with parameters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible in C# to collect information in an enum instead of a dedicated class?

Example how it would work in Java:

```
  public enum Action {

    JUMP( "JUMP", 1),
    CROUCH ("CROUCH", 2),
    ;

    private String animationId;
    private int buttonId;

    private Action( String animationId, int buttonId) {
      this.animationId = animationId;
      this.buttonId = buttonId;
    }

    public String getAnimationId() {
      return animationId;
    }

    public int getButtonId() {
      return buttonId;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can use `struct` if you don't want a class

Comment: no, but you can use a sealed class with public static fields as enum values

Comment: `enum` in C# & Java are different construction, see the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469287/c-sharp-vs-java-enum-for-those-new-to-c).

Comment: Hmmm...how do you enforce uniqueness?

Comment: You might want to check out Jon Skeet's [Enhanced enums in C#](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2006/01/05/classenum/) .  Not sure of the outcome

Comment: Or you could use attributes, a Dictionary, or a class, or a struct, or if you have more relationship data, you can store in a relationship DB

Comment: @TheGeneral but then you will not be able to use the type `Action`

Comment: Also check out _[How to implement a type-safe enum pattern in C#](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3198453/application-development/how-to-implement-a-type-safe-enum-pattern-in-c.html)_

Comment: @bluray i agree, for simple constraints and relationships where you want a quick in memory `enum` with the configuration of one or more relationship, i think attributes are a good solution (remembering it does use reflection) i guess the answer comes down to how far down this rabbit whole do we want to go

Comment: Your enum already contains integer value by default, first is 0, second is 1 and so on. You can also assign those values enum Action { Jump = 10, Crouch = 20 } then int value = (int)Action.Jump; or if((int)action > 10) { // it's a crouch}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can use static class fields instead:

```
public sealed class Action
{
    public static readonly Action JUMP = new Action("JUMP", 1);
    public static readonly Action CROUCH = new Action("CROUCH", 2);

    public string AnimationId { get; }
    public int ButtonId { get; }

    private Action(String animationId, int buttonId)
    {
        AnimationId = animationId;
        ButtonId = buttonId;
    }

    public override string ToString() => AnimationId;
}
```

Comment: _"...static class fields.."_ - That's what's called a _typesafe enum pattern_. _[How to implement a type-safe enum pattern in C#](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3198453/application-development/how-to-implement-a-type-safe-enum-pattern-in-c.html)_

Comment: I guess "No" was the correct answer. The ToString() should't be the AnimationId because my example was just a simple one. The main purpose is to not have out of context identifiers being used in the cs files.

Comment: @Roland, `ToString` implementation is not necessary and can be changed to anything you need. It is useful, for example, within string interpolation: `var a = $"Base action: {Action.JUMP}!"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use enum with attributes:

```
public enum Action{
  [MyValue("JUMP", 1)]
  JUMP,

  [MyValue("CROUCH", 2)]
  CROUCH
}

[AttributeUsage(
   AttributeTargets.Field |
   AttributeTargets.Method |
   AttributeTargets.Property,
   AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MyValueAttribute : System.Attribute{
  public string Value{get; private set}
  public string AnimationId{get; private set;}
  public MyValueAttribute(string animationId, string value){
     AnimationId = animationId;
     Value = value;
}
```

and you can get value as follows:

```
public static class EnumExtensions{
        public static string GetValue(this Enum value)
        {
            var type = value.GetType();
            var name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
            if (name == null) return string.Empty;
            var field = type.GetField(name);
            if (field == null) return string.Empty;
            var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(MyValueAttribute)) as MyValueAttribute;
            return attr != null ? attr.Value: string.Empty;
        }

        public static string GetAnimationId(this Enum value)
        {
            var type = value.GetType();
            var name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
            if (name == null) return string.Empty;
            var field = type.GetField(name);
            if (field == null) return string.Empty;
            var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(MyValueAttribute)) as MyValueAttribute;
            return attr != null ? attr.AnimationId: string.Empty;
        }
}
```

Usage:

```
Action.JUMP.GetValue();
Action.JUMP.GetAnimationId();
```

or you can use one method which return for example `Tuple` with `AnimationId` and `Value`

Comment: What about the `string` _animationId_?

Comment: Of course, this would give *all* enums a `GetAnimationId()` method. But I'm impressed that this works.

Comment: Not all enums. Method GetAnimationId would give only value for specified enum: `Action.JUMP.GetAnimationId()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely use attributes like suggested. However, you can call `.ToString()` on an enum value to get its name as a string value, and you can also assign int values to them. By default they are assigned 0-X based on index. However you could do this

```
public enum Action {
JUMP=1, 
CROUCH=2
}
```

And then to access these values

```
Action action = Action.JUMP;
int value = (int) action; //Is set to 1
string name = action.ToString(); //Is set to "JUMP"
```

While this certainly will not work in every case depending on how much you want your enum to store, for the situation you described this is much easier.

Comment: What about the `string` _animationId_?

Comment: In your example, you are setting your animationId to what the actual name of your enum value is. Which is string animationId = action.ToString(); If you wanted the animationId to be something other then the name of the enum value, this would not work.