# How to create Class-based Enums in Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, python, typescript, class, enums

I have this python code that I'm trying to convert to Javascript/Typescript

```py
import enum

class Shape(enum.Enum):
    RECTANGLE = 0
    CIRCLE = 1
    TRIANGLE = 2
    OTHER = 3

print(isinstance(data, Shape))
```

In Typescript, I can use enums, but this is not what I'm looking for. I need the ability to do this:

```js
const data = new Shape().RECTANGLE;
console.log(data instanceof Shape); // should return true
```

which wouldn't be possible to do using enums or objects.

EDIT: What's the syntax to build such a **class-based enum** in Typescript?

Comment: Would `(data in Shape)` work for you?

Comment: Can you explain more? `new Shape()` is obviously an `instanceof Shape`, but why would `someShape.RECTANGLE` also be an `instanceof Shape`? How is this used?

Comment: @CharlesBamford can you give an example?

Comment: @AlexWayne I'm trying to get the syntax for creating such a "class-based enum" in typescript

Comment: Something like `const Shapes = {RECTANGLE: "RECTANGLE", OTHER: "OTHER"}; const data = Shapes.OTHER; console.log(data in Shapes);`

Comment: So please explain what is a "class-based enum" means to you exactly? How is this used?

Comment: Thanks @Alex, that works, but I'm still curious to see if there is a possibility to re-create the same python enum class in JS/TS

Comment: I looked at how typescript's enum transpiles. You can do `enum Shapes = {/* whatever*/} ` then do `"RECTANGLE" in Shapes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a specific "syntax" in TypeScript for defining a class-based enum. But here's an example of a class named `Shape` that recognizes four types of shapes.

`Shape` provides a constructor that accepts an argument `shapeType`. If `shapeType` is not a recognized type, `create` throws an exception.

```js
class Shape {
  constructor(public shapeType: number) {
    if (!Shape.types.includes(shapeType)) {
      throw new Error(`Value ${shapeType} is not a valid shape type.`);
    }    
  }

  static readonly rectangle: number = 0;
  static readonly circle: number = 1;
  static readonly triangle: number = 2;
  static readonly other: number = 3;

  static get types(): number[] {
    return [
      Shape.rectangle,
      Shape.circle,
      Shape.triangle,
      Shape.other,  
    ];
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```js
const shape1: Shape = new Shape(Shape.triangle);
const isInstanceOf: boolean = shape1 instanceof Shape;
console.log(`Is Shape? ${isInstanceOf}; type is ${shape1.shapeType}`); // Is Shape? true; type is 2

try {
  const shape2: Shape = new Shape(42);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message); // Value 42 is not a valid shape type.
}
```

For reasons why you might want to move from an enumeration to a class, see [C# vs Java Enum (for those new to C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469287/1497596).

Answer (score 2):

Enums are a typescript concept, and are documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html). When you write an enum, typescript is creating a plain js object that matches the options of the enum, so the "in" operator can be used to check whether the provided value is a member of the enum.

Typescript enum.

```js
enum Direction {
  Up,
  Down,
  Left,
  Right,
}
```

What that is in javascript.

```js
var Direction = {
  '0': 'Up',
  '1': 'Down',
  '2': 'Left',
  '3': 'Right',
  Up: 0,
  Down: 1,
  Left: 2,
  Right: 3
}
```

Checking to see if a value is a member of the enum can be done with

```js
const foo = "Up";

// Unsafe, but quick and easy.
console.log(foo in Direction); // returns true.
console.log("toString" in Direction); // also returns true.

// Safe.
console.log(Direction.hasOwnProperty(foo)); // returns true.
console.log(Direction.hasOwnProperty(foo)); // returns false.
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. Although this does help, it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'd rather see an example using a class instead of object.

Comment: That's not how typescript does enums. You could roll your own implementation, but you would be on your own with that.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to use `enum`, just a basic `class` instead

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create Enums in JS/TS -

```
const enum OneDBServerPermission {
  RECTANGLE = 0
  CIRCLE = 1
  TRIANGLE = 2
  OTHER = 3
}
```

If you want to use it in other classes you can use **export keyword**

```
export const enum OneDBServerPermission {
  RECTANGLE = 0
  CIRCLE = 1
  TRIANGLE = 2
  OTHER = 3
}
```

Comment: I know how to create enums in JS/TS, thanks. I'm looking for class-based enums though.