# Nested C# Classes - Calling Outer Method From Inner

Tags: c#, iphone, nested-class

I have a ViewController class called GamePlay.  In GamePlay there is a nested class called MyPinAnnotationView.   When MyPinAnnotation's method TouchesBegan() gets called, I want to call a method CheckAnswer() from the parent GamePlay.

I do not want to create a new GamePlay instance because I have variables and instances already set.  Can I access the parent in some way?  ( Other than event listeners)

Comment: Here's an article Raymond Chen wrote about this a while back (with a postscript from me about JScript): http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/01/685248.aspx

Comment: And some more notes about this feature in JScript: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2005/05/02/414015.aspx

Comment: The above links from @EricLippert have gone stale.  Here's an updated link to Raymond Chen's post with an embedded link to Eric's.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060801-19/?p=30273

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The nested class will only be able to reference static members in the parent. If you want to access instance members, you need to get a reference to the instance. The simplest way to do this is to add it as a parameter to the constructor of `MyPinAnnotationView` like so:

```
class MyPinAnnotationView
{
  private GamePlay gamePlay;

  public MyPinAnnotationView(GamePlay gamePlay)
  {
    this.gamePlay = gamePlay;
  }

  public void TouchesBegan()
  {
    this.gamePlay.CheckAnswer();
  }
}
```

When you instantiate `MyPinAnnotationView` from `GamePlay`, just do this:

```
MyPinAnnotation annotation = new MyPinAnnotation(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the methods you want to access are not static, then you will need a reference to the parent object (I commonly pass the parent object reference in as a constructor parameter) in order to access its methods.  After all, your child class needs to know which instance of the parent class it is related to.

Answer (score 1):

The easy/quick way would be to keep a reference to the parent class in the child object, make `CheckAnswer()` public, then it's easy to call the method whenever needed... but you may want to go back and review the design to make sure this is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Nested classes should only be utilized by the parent class ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083032/why-would-i-ever-need-to-use-c-nested-classes)).  They shouldn't be publicly visible to other classes unless there is a really good reason.  Which there isn't.

I would suggest refactoring this. Try moving all the API for `GamePlay` into the `GamePlay` class.  In other words, `TouchesBegan()` should be called on the `GamePlay` class, which then calls into the `MyPinAnnotations` class.

No one else should know about `MyPinAnnotations` class - if they need to, then it is indicative of a design failure.