# use of inherit a nested class from the outer class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, nested

I was repeating knowledge about nested classes  and I saw this:

> In C#, the user is allowed to inherit a nested class from the outer class

I wonder did any one ever used it? what could be valid way of using class that inherit like that?

```
class A
{
    class B:A
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544882/inheritance-nestedclasses-in-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance + NestedClasses in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544882/inheritance-nestedclasses-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested classes can access all members of their enclosing type, including the constructors. You can use a private constructor to create a class with a fixed number of subclasses.

```
    public abstract class ResponseCode
    {
        public abstract int NumericCode { get; }

        private ResponseCode() { }

        public sealed class Success : ResponseCode
        {
            public override int NumericCode => 200;
        }

        public sealed class Error : ResponseCode
        {
            public override int NumericCode => 500;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- The scope of a nested class is bounded by the scope of its enclosing
  class.
- By default, the nested class is private.
- In C#, a user is allowed to inherit a class (including nested class)
  into another class.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-classes-in-c-sharp/