# Accessing a Nested Class

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Would I Ever Need to Use C# Nested Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083032/why-would-i-ever-need-to-use-c-sharp-nested-classes)

I'm doing it shorty, I have a class which looks like this:

```
namespace Blub {
    public class ClassTest {
        public void teest() {
            return "test";
        }

        public class AnotherTest {
            public void blub() {
                return "test";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can access to the function called "teest" like this, but how can I access to the function "blub" without doing another "new ClassTest.AnotherTest()"?

Accessing to the function teest:

```
Blub.ClassTest = new Blub.ClassTest();
ClassTest.teest(); //test will be returned
```

My try (and how I want it to, to access  on AnotherTest is this:

```
Blub.ClassTest = new Blub.ClassTest();
ClassTest.blub(); //test will be returned
```

Which don't work, I can just access to AnotherTest like this, how I dont want it:

```
Blub.ClassTest2 = new Blub.ClassTest.AnotherTest();
ClassTest.blub(); //test will be returned
```

Does someone know a solutions for this?

Comment: A related question is the following, which should help in understanding the benefit of nested classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083032/why-would-i-ever-need-to-use-c-sharp-nested-classes Effectively, by nesting a class, you are making a design decision about when you are going to be constructing that class and who has access to it.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring `AnotherTest` **inside** `ClassTest`, that's why you have to browse for it using `namespace.class.2ndClass`.

However, I suppose that you're not much aware of OO concepts, are you? If you declare a method inside a class, it will only be available for objects of *that* class, unless you declare it as `static`, what means that it would be a **class method** rather than a **instance method**.

If you want `ClassTest` to have 2 methods (`teest` and `blub`) simply declare both at the body of the class, like:

```
public class ClassTest
{
    public string teest()
    {
        return "test";
    }


    public string blub()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Also, note that if a method is declared as `void` it won't return anything (in fact, I think that your original code wouldn't even compile at all).

I'd recommend you to study OO a little deeper before trying to figure things out at your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to another class you have to make it a property in the first class.

```
namespace Blub {
   public class AnotherTest {
        public void blub() {
            return "test";
        }
    }


  public class ClassTest {
    public AnotherTest at = new AnotherTest();
    public void teest() {
        return "test";
    }


  }
}
```

Then access it like this:

```
 ClassTest x = new ClassTest();
 x.at.blub();
```