# extension methods nested within a class

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, .net-4.0, extension-methods

i wanted to know as i start to make some dramatic move from using regular helpers to more and more `extension methods` so they start to pile up ,

say my top main namespace is as follows :

the main namespace name is myname + last digit of year and current month

thats how i keep it organized as a helper namespace

```C#
namespace "myname212" 
{
    namespace DbRelated
    {
        some clasess & methods 
    }

    namespace styling
    {
        same as usual ..
    }

    // .... some more categories and...then

    //the extentions namespace

    namespace CustomExtentions
    {
        // simplest ext class and its first method 
        public static class ToNumber
        {
            public static int Toint(this Textbox TbxToConvrt)
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(TbxToConvrt.Text);
            }
            //some more of same subject 
        }
    }
}
```

but what if i have a more general catefory that has it own sub category logocally

```C#
namespace Extentions
{
    public static class MainCategory
    {
         public static class SubCat1 
         {
             public static some_method();
         }
         public static class SubCat2 
         {
             public static some_method();
         }
    }  
}
```

the a hierarchical stracture above will not work .

so is it true that if i'd like to build more categories i could only do it via

`nested namespaces` instead of `nested classes` ?

**is this what you do ?**

Comment: Why will not work? Is isn't compilable or you just don't like/don't accept it?

Comment: it will compile though won't be accesed as an extension (are you missing an assembly or ....)

Comment: @abatishchev did it ever work for you , did you try ? am i missing somthing ? the folowing strucure works for you as an extension ?: `namespace-> static class-> static class--> static method();` from outside to inside as like this works for you ?

Comment: @LoneXcoder why do you need to nest static classes containing extension methods? It looks very clear to nest namespaces...even to keep your year-namings: `namespace Extensions.SomeName2012.January`, then  `namespace Extensions.SomeName2012.February` and so on...so you only need to add the suitable `using`

Comment: Okay, I see now. You nest not namespaces but classes. That can not work indeed.

Comment: @LoneXcoder read [Why Would I Ever Need to Use C# Nested Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083032/why-would-i-ever-need-to-use-c-sharp-nested-classes)

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov thx, ill have a look now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest namespaces *instead*:

```
namespace My.Nested.Namespace.So.Far
{
    public static class BlaExtensions
    {
    }
}
```

or even:

```
namespace My.Nested.Namespace
{
    public static class FooExtensions
    {
    }

    namespace So.Far
    {
        public static class BlaExtensions
        {
        }
    }
}
```

[should work too](http://ideone.com/o4O1D8).

Comment: thank you for answering just wanted to make sure i have no other choice