# How come usage of non static members in static context is not give an error?

Tags: c#, static, enums

Here is the piece of C# code in which i have a doubt.

```
class Program
{
    class DOB { int d, m, y; }
    int a;
    enum Month { jan, feb, mar };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        a = 6;                      //Showing error
        DOB d = new DOB();   //DOB is not static; still no error.
        Month m = 0;     //Month is non static but not showing error(I know it cannot be static)
        Console.WriteLine(m);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The assignment for the variable **a** is showing error because it is a non-static member.
At the same time the class **DOB** and the enum **Month** are also non static, but it is not whing error.

Comment: You are not _assigning_ a value, you are instanciating a new object. Regardind your `enum` you're actualy doing the same thing: creating a new member of type `Month`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access instance members from a static class or method.

`a` is an instance field of `Program`, so you get an error at `a = 6`.
`DOB d = new DOB()` simply creates a new object of the `DOB` class and assigns it to a local variable.
`Month m = 0` also creates a new local variable.

If you had written

```
[...]
DOB d;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    d = new DOB();
```

you would have gotten the same error as for `a`.

Comment: I understand the error at **a**. Class **DOB** is also a member of the class **Program**; How can i able to use it? I'm not so clear about this. I'm thinking that variable **a** and class **DOB** are the same level members of the class **Program**. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: @sanjay `DOB` is not a member of `Program`, it's a nested class.

Comment: ok, i got the difference. Bassically i'm learning C# (have knowledge in java). I just tried the same program in java, and it is showing the error near the object creation for DOB. In java, we need to create the object for Program first, and then we have the call the constructor of the DOB with the isntance of Program. What is the exact difference?

Comment: The access modifier for nested classes default to private. So nobody except for members of `Program` can instantiate the `DOB` class. That's the main difference of having nested classes. It's not terribly useful, but there are some use cases where this can be nice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083032/why-would-i-ever-need-to-use-c-sharp-nested-classes