# Foreach doesn't find nested class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to make a model for mvc page like this:

```
public class Body
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public class Hand
    {
        public List<Fingers> fingers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foot
    {
        public List<Toes> toes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Head
    {
        public Nose nose {get; set;}
        public List<Ears> ears { get; set; }
        public List<Eyes> eyes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then have a class for Fingers like this:

```
public class Fingers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then access it like this in my view:

```
@model Models.Body
@foreach (var fingers in Model.Hand.Fingers)
{
    @Html.RadioButton("fingerList", fingers.Description)     
}
```

Am I doing my model wrong? Right now VS doesn't recognize the `Model.Hand` in the `foreach`, much less the `Model.Hand.Fingers`.  I don't want to make the `@model` `IEnumerable` because this page should only show one `person`, but it can have multiple lists of `fingers`, `toes`, etc.

Comment: What is the error? it does not compíle? or in the execution time fingers are not displayed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Body` class has no property `Hand` on it.

Beyond that, your Hand class has `fingers` but in razor you refer to it with `Fingers`.

I don't know if you really intend to have your classes be nested, but you need to add properties onto your `Body` class for the ones you want (sticking with your property capitalization conventions):

```
public class Body
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Hand hand { get; set; }
    public Foot foot { get; set; }
    public Head head { get; set; }

    public class Hand
    {
        public List<Fingers> fingers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foot
    {
        public List<Toes> toes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Head
    {
        public Nose nose {get; set;}
        public List<Ears> ears { get; set; }
        public List<Eyes> eyes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and then you need to refer to the properties with casing that matches your properties, not the class names:

```
@model Models.Body
@foreach (var fingers in Model.hand.fingers)
{
    @Html.RadioButton("fingerList", fingers.Description)     
}
```

I would also argue that your casing/capitalization is incorrect, but that's not the point of your question.

Comment: What are the advantages/disadvantages of having them nested

Comment: That's a discussion for another thread. But here's a rabbit hole you can go down: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083032/why-would-i-ever-need-to-use-c-sharp-nested-classes

Answer (score 2):

Since you are accessing the Hand property of your model which is Body type, You should add a property called Hand to your Body class.

```
public class Hand
{
    public List<Fingers> Fingers { get; set; }
}
public class Body
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public Hand Hand {set;get;}
    public Foot Foot { set;get;}
    public Head Head { set;get;}
}
public class Foot
{
    public List<Toes> toes { get; set; }
}
public class Head
{
   public Nose nose {get; set;}
   public List<Ears> ears { get; set; }
   public List<Eyes> eyes { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your GET action, you need to initialize the `Hand` property

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var vm = new Body { Hand= new Hand { Fingers = new List<Finger>()} };
  return View(vm);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a property called `Fingers` in your `Body` class instead of a nested class called `Hand`:

```
public List<Fingers> Fingers { get; set; }
```

Then you could:

```
@foreach (var fingers in Model.Fingers)
{
    @Html.RadioButton("fingerList", fingers.Description)     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't add the properties to Body class!?

```
public class Body
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Hand Hand {get;set;}
    public Foot Foot {get;set;}
    public Head Head {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that your Model is missing some itinialization; no setters have been called yet. So...

```
public class Hand
{
    public Hand()
    {
      Fingers = new List<Fingers>();
    }
}
```

Same goes for the `Hand` property. It is likely `null`, no your `foreach loop` will not work.

Side note: don't pluralize your class names. It should be `Finger` and `Toe`, since you have a list of it.