# Accessing static nested class of a Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class :

```
class MyClass 
{
   public static class MyNestedClass 
   {
       public const int M1 = 1;
       public const int M2 = 2;
   }
}

class MyClass2 
{
   public static class MyNestedClass 
   {
       public const int M1 = 1;
       public const int M2 = 2;
   }
}
```

and a generic function :

```
private static void Work<T>()
{
    Type myType = typeof(T.MyNestedClass);
    myType.GetFields().Select(....);
    // .. use T here as well..
}
```

I get error : `error CS0704: Cannot do member lookup in 'T' because it is a type parameter`.

Since `MyNestedClass` is static class, when i try to pass it as another Generic Type argument as :

```
private static void Work<T, S>()
{
    Type myType = typeof(S);
    myType.GetFields().Select(....);
    // .. use T here as well..
}
```

calling via,

```
Work<MyClass, MyClass.MyNestedClass>();
```

gives me error : `static types cannot be used as type arguments`

What is the right way to access nested static and non-static class in c# ?

Comment: `private static void Work<T>() where T: MyClass` don't know if this can work too :)

Comment: @CodeNotFound I have multiple classes all of which has `MyNestedClass` inside it. use case : EventProvider and `Tasks` is static inner class.

Comment: I will read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083032/why-would-i-ever-need-to-use-c-sharp-nested-classes) then.

Comment: "I have multiple classes all of which has MyNestedClass inside it". Do you? How is the compiler supposed to know this?

Comment: Why are you even using nested classes here? That seems like a horrible code smell to me.

Comment: Static types can't be used as generic arguments. You can't do `List<MyClass.MyNestedClass>`... Even if `MyNestedClass` wasn't nested it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: `EventSource` in c# dictates to have nested class `Task` with multiple `EventTask ` inside it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource(v=vs.110).aspx Similarly EventProvider in my case.

Comment: If i remove `static` from class, will `T.MyNestedClass` help ?

Comment: Bear in mind that wherever you identify a *type* by name in your code, the compiler has to identify *the type that you're talking about* and put a token into the IL that identifies the specific type - which will either be a concrete type or a generic type parameter. When you say something like `A.B.C` then the type token that gets emitted is for `C`. It's **not** "first find type/namespace `A`, then *separately* find a `B` within it and then find a `C` within *that*.

Comment: @mm8 I thought a way to enforce by `constraints`.

Comment: That MSDN link is not great code. The nested type could quite easily be `private` for example, but there is no gain for it to be a nested class.

Comment: @DavidG It can't be private as it's used by EventSource to generate dynamic manifests.

Comment: And i totally agree it's not great code, but not nesting is not an option for me.

Comment: @AshishNegi: You can't use constraints to enforce a type to have a nested type...

Comment: The Generic is pointless here. It's doing nothing, just replace `T` with `MyClass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `T` has no nested type called `MyNestedClass` unless you specify `T` to actually be a `MyClass`. You can then use the `GetNestedTypes()` method to retrieve the nested type:

```
private static void Work<T>() where T : MyClass
{
    Type myType = typeof(T).GetNestedTypes().FirstOrDefault();
    //...
}
```

There is a `GetNestedType` method that accepts a type name `string` available as well.

But you can't use constraints to enforce a specific type to have a nested type.

Comment: GetNestedType("Tasks") is better, if i have to use reflection.

Comment: If `T : MyClass` what's the point in the generic at all? You might as well just use `MyClass` in place of `T`?

Comment: @Liam: Yes, unless MyClass is some kind of base class or interface.

Comment: @Liam i have multiple classes with same nested class. Real world use case : Multiple `EventSource` and `Tasks` nested class.

Comment: *"you can't use constraints to enforce a specific type to have a nested type..."* +1

Comment: Oh, and by the way (since it hasn't been mentioned elsewhere on this page), from the perspective of the nested (or "enclosed") type, its containing ("outer") type can be discovered via its `Type.DeclaringType` property...