# Private class with Public method?

Tags: c#, class, access-modifiers, public-method

Here is a piece of code:

```
private class myClass
{
   public static void Main()
   {

   }
}

        'or'

private class myClass
{
   public void method()
   {

   }
}
```

I know, first one will not work. And second one will.

**But why first is not working? Is there any specific reason for it?**

Actually looking for a solution in this perspective, thats why made it bold. Sorry

Comment: Hard to guess at what you mean, neither is valid.  Only a nested class can be private.  A non-nested class can't be private because then it can never be used by any code.

Comment: @rapsalands - what specifically do you mean by "will not work"?

Comment: @Hans: Why it is not used by any one? Private class can be accessed with in namespace, can be instantiated and public members can be accessed through it

Comment: @Richard: It will not compile

Comment: No.  The compiler is pretty clear about it: *Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, or protected internal*

Comment: @Hans: Thanks, you are right. I misunderstood few things. Thaks for bearing with me. None of them will work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It would be meaningful in this scenario; you have a public class `SomeClass`, inside which you want to encapsulate some functionality that is only relevant to `SomeClass`. You could do this by declaring a private class (`SomePrivateClass` in my example) within `SomeClass`, as shown below.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private class SomePrivateClass
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {

        }
    }

    // Only SomeClass has access to SomePrivateClass,
    // and can access its public methods, properties etc
}
```

This holds true regardless of whether `SomePrivateClass` is `static`, or contains `public static` methods.

I would call this a *nested class*, and it is explored in another [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454218/private-inner-classes-in-c-sharp-why-arent-they-used-more-often).

Comment: `Only SomeClass has access to [...] its public methods.` - not quite accurate. If you give a reference of the nested private class to someone outside of the outer class, it will have access to those public methods too (see my answer for an example).

Comment: Good point made by Allon. However, in this situation you're supplying a reference to an instance of a private class that implements a public interface. So the "someone outside" is accessing the private class via the supplied interface, it has no explicit knowledge of the private class itself.

Comment: What can access `DoSomething`?

Comment: @Frederick - anything inside `SomeClass` that has access to an instance of `SomePrivateClass` will be able to call `DoSomething` on that instance.

Answer (score 3):

Richard Ev gave a use case of access inside a nested classes. Another use case for nested classes is private implementation of a public interface:

```
public class MySpecialCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{ 
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new MySpecialEnumerator(...);
    }

    private class MySpecialEnumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        public bool MoveNext() { ... }
        public T Current
        { 
            get { return ...; }
        }
        // etc...
    } 
}
```

This allows one to provide a private (or protected or internal) implementation of a public interface or base class. The consumer need not know nor care about the concrete implementation. This can also be done without nested classes by having the `MySpecialEnumerator` class be internal, as you cannot have non-nested private classes.

The BCL uses non-public implementations extensively. For example, objects returned by LINQ operators are non-public classes that implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

This code is syntactically correct. But the big question is: is it useful, or at least usable in the context where you want to use it? Probably not, since the `Main` method must be in a `public` class.

Answer (score 0):

`Main()` method is where application execution begin, so the reason you cannot compile your first class (with `public static void Main()`) is because you already have `Main` method somewhere else in your application. The compiler don't know where to begin execute your application.

Your application must have only one `Main` method to compile with default behavior otherwise you need to add [/main](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3eht538.aspx) option when you compile it.

Comment: thanks dude, but I don't have 2 Main methods. I modifies the one in Program.cs. The issue here is private class not method name. Still thanks.

Comment: What's the type of your project, application or library? It will be helpful if you add all code to your question though. :)

Comment: private class is not problem here.

Comment: its application, in library whats the need of Main method