# How to access private class method in nested class

Tags: c#, oop

How can I access the method `DoSomething()` here? I can't access it when I create an object of type `SomeClass`.

On the other hand, what is the use of having a private class inside a public class?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string str = string.Empty;

    private class SomePrivateClass
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: You can access `DoSomething` from methods of `SomeClass` (using an instance of `SomePrivateClass`).

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dh62Hk

Comment: [Private inner classes in C# - why aren't they used more often?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454218/private-inner-classes-in-c-sharp-why-arent-they-used-more-often)

Comment: Since you marked you question as OOP - it's generally advised not to use nested types when you intend to access members of the nested type.

Comment: Where do you want to access DoSomething from? From SomeClass? Or are you trying to access it from a completely different class?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the object of the nested class inside the outer class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string  str= string.Empty;

    private class SomePrivateClass
    {
         public void DoSomething()
         {

         }
    }
    public void CreateObjectOfSomePrivateClass()
    {
        SomePrivateClass obj = new SomePrivateClass();
        obj.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DoSomething` is an *instance* method, and a `public` one, meaning that any code which has access to the definition of that type (class), can in fact invoke that method. And since `SomePrivateClass` is a private class of `SomeClass`, then it can only be instantiated **within** `SomeClass`. You should concentrate on reading more about the difference between static and instance members (e.g. [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx)).

Having said that, one thing that a private class *can* do is access private fields of a parent class (both instance and static, but again you need to have an *instance* of a parent class in order to call its instance methods), which other classes can't.

Comment: Nitpick: "any code which can instantiate an object of that type" - or, more precisely, any code which can get hold of an instance of that type (even if it cannot itself instantiate the type).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: yes, that's correct, or maybe even better, as long as the class definition is visible to the client code, since you can easily get an instance of a private or an internal class through a public interface or its base type which doesn't have to expose the method at all.