# Create object of class in void and use it in main

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scope

I've got a problem with the following code:

```
public class Player
{
    public int money;
    public void setMoney(int amount)
    {
        money = amount;
    }
}

public void init()
{
    Player Player1 = new Player();
}

public void main()
{
    Player1.money = 9001;
}

private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    init();
    main();
}
```

When I run the given code I get an error that Player1 was not available in that context.
So I guess i can't create an Player object in init and then use it in main.

How can I solve that problem?

Regards, dncrft

Comment: Please don't post fake code.

Comment: Player1 is a local variable. It is only accesible from withing the init() method.

Comment: Yeah, i realised that. But I can't add a "public" keyword or something like that :/

By the way, it is no fake code. Just a shorter and english translated version of my original one.

Comment: This code is trivially simple. Surely the real problem is more complex. In which case the correct solution for the real problem is likely different from the solution to this problem.

Comment: `voic` is not a keyword. The code was fake. We have no confidence that this is your real code.

Comment: Seriously need to learn OOPS concepts. Classes and objects are base of OOPS, so understand them

Comment: Bro, i fixed the     voic     error 4 minutes ago.

Comment: Yes, but my point stands. You posted fake code. Which means that there may be other errors made when you typed out the code rather than pasted it from your editor. You don't have to listen to my advice. But I'm still going to offer it. Never post fake code. Always copy code directly from your editor so that we are sure to have the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you declare an instance of `Player` in `init()`, the variable scoping rules in `C#` define that you can not use a variable outside the scope it defined. so `Player1` is only accessible in `init()`. If you want to use it outside the `init()` you should define it in a scope that is visible to `main()`

```
public class Player
{
 public int money;
 public void setMoney(int amount)
 {
  money = amount;
 }
}
Player Player1;
public void init()
{
 Player1 = new Player();
}

public void main()
{
 Player1.Money = 9001;
}

private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 init();
 main();
}
```

some problems in your code:
1. `Player.money` is field, if it has a setter try set it private and use a setter and getter or make it as a property, `public int money { set; get; }`
2. Consider [naming conventions in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. Consider using [nested classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454218/private-inner-classes-in-c-sharp-why-arent-they-used-more-often)

so I suggest this code

```
public class Player
{
   public int Money { get; set; }
}

public MainForm : Form
{
  private Player player1;

  public void Init()
  {
     this.player1 = new Player();
  }

  public void Main()
  {
     this.player1.money = 9001;
  }

  private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Init();
    Main();
  }
}
```

Comment: A naming convention would be `Pascal Case` for properties. As stated in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx. So, in his case, it would be `Money`

Comment: I just changed OP's code, an edit is on it's way @LuisLavieri

Comment: Okey, this would be a solution - also the getter and setter are good ideas - I haven't written object orientated code too long.
The scope thing lead me to the right direction, I guess I know another way better solution now.. will try it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that instance of `Player` is out of scope. Also, you may want to use the shorthand declaration for your property.

```
public class Player
{
    public int Money {get; set;}
}
public void main()
{
    Player player = new Player();
    player.Money = 9001;
}
```